# Determining if the subset of two vectors is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set containing $\{\mathbf{w_1},\mathbf{w_2}\}$ made of only two vectors $\mathbf{w_1}=(1,0,-5)$ and $\mathbf{w_2}=(2,3,4)$ a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$? 
I don't know what to do about the fact that two vectors with no condition are given. I'm pretty sure I'm overcomplicating this big time.

Comment: Hint: See if they're closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: A set of two different vectors in a vector space over an infinite field is never a subspace.

Comment: Notice that $\mathbf0\notin\{\mathbf{w_1} ,\mathbf{w_2}\}$.